# Constructing continuous function using locally finite basis

Tags: general-topology, continuity

(Munkres) Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $X=$ $\bigcup_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A,$ and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be such that $\left.f\right|_{A}$ is continuous, for every $A \in \mathscr{A}$.

We say $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite if for every $x \in X,$ there is a neighborhood $U \subset X$ of $x$ such that $\{A \in \mathscr{A} \mid U \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite. Show that if $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite and if each $A \in \mathscr{A}$ is closed in $X,$ then $f$ is continuous. Give an example to show that the result may fail if $\mathscr{A}$ is not locally finite.

I'm new to topology. My attempt so far:

$\forall\;V\subseteq Y$ such that $V$ is open in $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)\cap A$ is open in $A$ for every $A \in \mathscr{A}$. Another point to note is, if $x \in int\;A$ then $f$ is continuous at $x$, therefore we only need to prove continuity for points on the boundaries of sets in $\mathscr{A}$ (even though I'm confused about the fact that in analysis we talk about continuity at a point but in topology we only talk about continuity of the function as a whole, defined by pre-images of open sets being open). Also, for some finite subcollection $\{A_i\}_i$ of $\mathscr{A}$, $x \in \cap_i A_i$ and $x \notin A$ for all other $A \in \mathscr{A}$. For any sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$, $\exists N$ s.t. for all $n > N$, $x_n \in A_i$ for some $i$ (we would not be able to say this without local finiteness). Therefore by continuity of $f|_A$, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.

I did the sequential proof based off my analysis courses where I have dealt with only metric spaces. I'm not sure if the sequential proof is correct in the context of topology.

Comment: We can talk continuity at a point $x$ as follows: for every open set $U$ containing $f(x)$ there exists an open set $V$ containing $x$ such that $V \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ (note the analogy with the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition). Also, it is not clear how $x_n \in A_i$ for some i$ follows with the local finiteness property, can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

The key is that a locally finite collection $\mathcal{A}$ of sets is so-called *closure-preserving* in the sense that $\overline{\bigcup \mathcal{A}} = \bigcup \{\overline{A}\mid A \in \mathcal{A}\}$.

Then if $\mathcal{A}$ is a locally finite family of closed sets and $f\restriction_A$ is continuous for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $f$ is indeed continuous: let $F \subseteq Y$ be closed. By the assumptions $(f\restriction_A)^{-1}[F] = f^{-1}[F] \cap A$ is closed in $A$ for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$, and as all such $A$ are themselves closed in $X$, $f^{-1}[F] \cap A$ is closed in $X$ as well, for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$. It's trivial that the family $\{f^{-1}\cap A \mid A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is also locally finite (a "shrinking" of $\mathcal{A}$) and so by closure preservingness:

$$\overline{f^{-1}[F]} = \overline{\bigcup \{ A \cap f^{-1}[F]\mid A \in \mathcal{A}\}} = \bigcup \{A \cap f^{-1}[F]\mid A \in \mathcal{A}\}  =f^{-1}[F]$$

so that $f^{-1}[F]$ is closed and so $f$ is continuous.

Finally to show the closure prervingness of the locally finite $\mathcal{A}$, we note that for every fixed $A \in \mathcal{A}$, we have that $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{\bigcup \mathcal{A}}$ by mononicity, and so also

$\bigcup \{\overline{A}\mid A \in \mathcal{A}\} \subseteq \overline{\bigcup \mathcal{A}}$, is then clear. For the reverse, we pick $x \in \overline{\bigcup \mathcal{A}}$ and we pick an open neighbourhood $O_x$ such that $\mathcal{A}(x):=\{A \in \mathcal{A}: A \cap O_x \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite. It's clear that $x \notin \overline{A}$ for any $A \notin \mathcal{A}(x)$. So *if* $x \notin A$ for *every* $A \in \mathcal{A}(x)$, we could pick a neighbourhood $O_A$ of $x$ that each $O_A \cap A = \emptyset$, for each $A \in \mathcal{A}(x)$. But then the open neighbourhood (finite intersection) $O_x \cap \bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{A}(x)} O_A$ of $x$ would be disjoint from $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$ altogether, which is a contradiction. So in fact, $x$ *must* be in one of the set $\overline{A}$ for *some* $A \in \mathcal{A}(x)$, so in $\bigcup \{\overline{A}\mid A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ as well ,finishing the proof of the inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

In metric spaces the topology is completely characterized by the convergent sequences, but in topological spaces in general this is not the case: a point $x$ can be a limit point of a set $A$ even if no sequence in $A$ converges to $x$. Thus, you need to find an approach that doesn’t use sequences. It’s also not enough to know that $x$ belongs to only finitely many of the sets in $\mathscr{A}$, because it might still be a limit point of infinitely many of them. In technical terms, it’s not enough for the collection $\mathscr{A}$ to be *point finite*, meaning that no point is in infinitely many members of $\mathscr{A}$: we really do need to know that $\mathscr{A}$ is *locally* finite.

And in fact the result is false as stated: you need to assume further that the members of $\mathscr{A}$ are **closed** sets. I see that Henno Brandsma has already explained how to prove that in that case $f$ is continuous, so I’ll simply add an example to show that the result is not true in general.

Let $X=[0,2]$ with the usual topology. Let $\mathscr{A}=\{[0,1),[1,2]\}$; $\bigcup\mathscr{A}=X$, and since $\mathscr{A}$ is finite, it is certainly locally finite. Let $Y=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology, and let

$$f:X\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x\in[0,1]\\
1,&\text{if }x\in(1,2]\,;
\end{cases}$$

clearly $f\upharpoonright[0,1)$ and $f\upharpoonright[1,2]$ are continuous, but $f^{-1}[\{0\}]=[0,1]$ is not open in $X$ even though $\{0\}$ is open in $Y$, so $f$ is not continuous.

In fact we can construct such an example in any space that does not have the discrete topology. Let $X$ be such a space; then there is an $A\subseteq X$ such that $A$ is not clopen. Let $\mathscr{A}=\{A,X\setminus A\}$, let $Y$ be as before, and let

$$f:X\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x\in A\\
1,&\text{if }x\in X\setminus A\,;\,;
\end{cases}$$

clearly $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite and $f\upharpoonright A$ and $f\upharpoonright X\setminus A$ are continuous. $\{0\}$ is clopen in $Y$, but $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is not clopen in $X$, so $f$ is not continuous.

Note: In case you’ve not yet encountered the term a *clopen* set is one that is both closed and open. Since $A$ in that last example is not clopen, either it is not open, or it is not closed (or both).

Comment: Thanks so much. I think we had to give an example of a collection of closed sets which cover the space but this collection is not locally finite. The examples here are cases where the collection is locally finite but the sets are not closed.

Comment: @Canine360: You’re very welcome.

Comment: So could you share any examples of the former? Where continuity on X does not hold even if every A is closed, because $\mathscr{A}$ is not locally finite?

Comment: @Canine360: Let $X=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ with the topology that it inherits from $\Bbb R$. Let $\mathscr{A}=\big\{\{x\}:x\in X\big\}$; this is a family of closed sets covering $X$, but it is not locally finite at $0$. Let $f(0)=0$, and let $f(x)=1$ for $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$. Clearly $f$ is continuous on each member of $\mathscr{A}$ but not continuous on $X$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Canine360: You’re welcome.